# How to autofill vertically and change column instead of row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vba

I currently have a formula in another worksheet where I refer to a specific variable cell:

```
=Units!B3
```

When I drag using autofill, it fills and changes the row e.g B4,B5,B6. However, I want to drag it down and make it change to C3,D3,E3,F3,G3, etc

How could I do this? I am aware of transpose, but didn't give me any luck.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(Units!$3:$3,(ROW(1:1)-1)+2)
```

The `+2` is the starting column in this case the second or Column B.  Now as it is dragged down it will increment the column.

Comment: Thanks, but when I drag it down it continues to fetch values vertically, rather than move to the next value horizontally. Do I have to set an absolute reference somewhere?

Comment: @gcat remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.